# Edit in comments is viewed after 5 minutes

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What is the point of seeing `edit` link in comments even after 5 minutes which makes the user to think the comment can be edited. Is there any particular reason?

What if the link is disabled or removed after 5 minutes which will be more useful.

Comment: Because it's easier to leave it there rather than come up with a complicated solution to remove it after 5 minutes. Saves server time calls...